# change fields of register form according to need zfcuser zf2 (different fields)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am creating an application using zf2. I have successfully installed **zfcuser**. I have two types of user in my application: `Sponsor` and `Itemowner`. I need to change the registration form and I have successfully changed it. But the main problem is I need to add different fields for both cases:

I have two buttons named sponsor and owner. If owner is clicked then i need different fields and when sponsor is clicked i need different fields. I can add fields by adding below code in onBootstrap method

```
 $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $events->attach('ZfcUser\Form\Register','init', function($e) {
            $form = $e->getTarget();
               $form->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                    'id' => 'name',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Name*',
            ),
                'required' => true,
        ));
        });
```

But i dont know how can i achieve different for both the cases. Please suggest some workarounds or tricks.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but how did you solve this? I have the same situation - 2 user types, which should share the ZfcUser functionality.

Comment: I actually placed all the fields which were required and then while rendring the view i am using a if...else statement to control the output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think it's better to separate Sponsors and Owners registrations?